# Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory in cstddef QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt

When I want to compile my Qt project, debuger shows me that stddef.h was not included into ...\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include. I tried to solve this problem using adding to system Environmental Variables path to Win SDK Kits (folder include). But this doesnt solve my problem. Also I instaled Windows Universal CRT SDK but this giving me nothing. Also I tried to reinstall VS and Qt,check Qt for update, add to environment variable PATH path to folder bin from MSVC folders and change include in cstddef from stddef.h to stddef. This is the list of my environment variable PATH:

1. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
2. C:\Program Files\dotnet\
3. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
4. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\
5. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0

And this is user environment setting PATH:

1. C:\Users\karat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
2. C:\Users\karat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
3. C:\Users\karat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
4. C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.1\bin
5. C:\Users\karat.dotnet\tools
6. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
7. %USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools

Could you recommend me a way to solve this problem and tell me why this could happen at all?

Comment: Fyi, *"and change include in cstddef from stddef.h to stddef"* - don't do that. You don't own that header. you shouldn't have to touch implementation headers of any kind, and doing so does nothing but guarantee your code will never stand a chance of building anywhere but your host (and as you can see, even that's no guarantee). Also, the PATH has *nothing* to do with where headers are located. That typically comes from either the system INCLUDE environment variable, or command-line addendums via a `-I path` ot `/I path` switch. Using a native tools development command prompt wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I followed your advice and decided to check what is in the INCLUDE variable, but it simply does not exist. I tried to add it manually but it gave no result